# VBA: How to insert Symbol based on cell value using character number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Objective: I would like a Green Arrow pointing upward in cell `B1` if the value in cell `A1` is positive, but if the value in cell `A1` is negative, I'd like a Red Arrow pointing down.  The macro recorder uses the output `"?"` when inserting symbols so I'm not sure how change the code properly.  What code should I use to replace the question marks?

> Char Code (Down Arrow): 2193
>     Char Code (Up Arrow): 2191

```
If Range("A1") > 0 Then
 Range("B1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "?"
 Range("B1").Select
 With Selection.Font
    .Color = -11489280
    .TintAndShade = 0
Else 
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "?"
 Range("B1").Select
 With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
```

Comment: You know you can have conditional formatting to achieve what you want? **HOME | Conditional Formatting | Icon Sets**

Comment: That would be fantastic, I looked into conditional formatting but could not figure it out.  How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip.  I'm going to try this right now

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/icon-sets.html

Comment: Thank you, I did this and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub arrow()
    With Range("B1")
        If Range("A1") > 0 Then
            .Value = "#"
            .Font.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            .Value = "$"
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        .Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this!